# Ubuntu won't startup install on Intel mac mini

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, mac

When i'm trying to install Ubuntu on my late 2009 Mac mini 3,1, i run the installer as usual. I wait, and then my screen is black. I left the computer like this for 15 minutes, screen still black. Help!

Comment: What iso file did you use? Did you use a DVD or flash drive to install? If a DVD, then how to you burn the DVD. If a flash drive, then how did you transfer the iso files to this drive? Did you the startup manage to boot the DVD or flash drive? Are you planing to use the startup manager, rEFInd or some other method to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Used a Flash Drive, burned the LTS desktop iso, rebooted, started up rEFInd and boot the grub2 disk, then i selected "nomodeset" parameter, and then screen display changes to an unsupported one.